# Programmatically assigning security role to user on login in JSF website

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

I have setup my `web.xml` to deny access to certain pages within my site and redirect a user to a login page if they are not yet logged in. And I have defined a role simply called `USER` It looks like this:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>mis</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/signin.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

In my `signing.xhtml` page I want to check the user's credentials manually (we are using injected headers from a  reverse proxy to handle the actual security) and then assign the user to a specific role based on certain conditions.

Is there a way to way to programmatically assign the current user and the roles that the user has? Or do I have to use the JBOSS/Glassfish users setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the best way to do this is not to use the `security-constraints` but rather use the `filter` option. First create a class that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` and implement the `doFilter` method:

```
public class UserRoleFilter implements Filter {    
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        //Manually check that the current user can access pages
        //I did that by storing stuff in the session which you can access by 
        //request.getSession().getAttribute(someKey);
        if(!userHasAccessToRestrictedPages) {
            HttpServletResponse r = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            r.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/signin.xhtml");
            return;
        }

        next.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Then in the `web.xml` file remove the `security-constraints`, `login-config` and `security-role` and replace with (where `filter-class` refers to the class above):

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>UserRoleFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>security.UserRoleFilter</filter-class>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>UserRoleFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

That should do it.